# Know if there are lists of lists or not - Python

Tags: python, list

Suppose we have two lists:

```
A = [2, 3, [6, 7], 0]
B = [4, 7, 10, 2]
```

I want to input those values to a function like this:

```
def gettype(self, a):
 for x in a:
    if isinstance(x, list):
     ident = True
    else:
     ident = False
  return ident
```

That returns True if there are a list of lists or false otherwise.

```
ident = gettype(A)
print ident
True

ident = gettype(B)
print ident
False
```

PS: That function above doesn't work, it's returning False in both cases

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Like

```
A = [2, 3, [6, 7], 0]
B = [4, 7, 10, 2]


def has_lists(lst):
    return any(isinstance(x, list) for x in lst)

print has_lists(A) # True
print has_lists(B) # False
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you change the value of `ident` for every member of the list. So in fact you only get True if the last element of the list is a list.

Try this instead. If there is a list in the list, return True. If the end of the list is reached without encountering a list, return False.

```
def gettype(self, a):
 for x in a:
    if isinstance(x, list):
     return True
  return False
```

Answer (score 1):

You are iterating over all elements of the list. The problem is you are overwriting the value of `ident` and as the last value of the list is an `integer` the function returns `False`.

You have to return `True` when you find the first case of `list` element like the other implementations in the other answers do.

Answer (score 1):

The issue with your code is that you update `ident` on each iteration, and the last value in `A` is not a list, hence the `False` result. Here's what you likely want:

```
def gettype(self, a):
    for x in a:
        if isinstance(x, list):
            return True
    return False
```

Notice that the `return True` statement immediately breaks out of the `for` loop and terminates the algorithm as soon as a list element is encountered.